# How to find the same set of elements found in div in html document using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example following code have a three div block.In this block i need div 1    and 3 are same elements.

```
<div>
 <div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <a>Test</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a>Test</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <a>Test</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far.. include JS in OP

Comment: First I Can select div like "<div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <a>Test</a>
 </div>". Then I need to find same set in the html document

Comment: what happens if the indentation is different or the text inside the elements is not the same?

Comment: @Pete My indentation find the div block should have a same child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can select every `div` has some html. If html of `div` is equal to first `div`, it is equal to it.

```js
$(".parent > div").each(function(){
    if ($(this).html().trim() == $(".parent > div:first").html().trim())
        $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div>
       <p>Test</p>
       <a>Test</a>
   </div>
   <div>
       <a>Test</a>
   </div>
   <div>
       <p>Test</p>
       <a>Test</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

*Note that: the code work if html of divs are exactly equal.*

Answer (score 0):

please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=0;
  var msg = "";
  var elements = [];
  $("#check div").each(function(){
    var _currentHTML = $(this).html();   
    i = (i+1);
    var j = 0;
    $("#check div").each(function(){
      var _checkHTML = $(this).html();   
      j = (j+1);
      if((i!=j) && (_currentHTML == _checkHTML) && $.inArray(i+'_'+j,elements) == -1 && $.inArray(j+'_'+i,elements)==-1)      {
        elements.push(i+'_'+j);
        msg += i+" and "+j+" divs are same.\n";
      }
    });    
  });
  console.log(msg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check">
  <div>
    <p>Test</p>
    <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Test</p>
    <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Test</p>
    <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```